# DOM: determine if the anchorNode or focusNode is on the left side

Tags: javascript, dom

This method...

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode
```

...tells us where the selection of text STARTS.

This method...

```
window.getSelection().focusNode
```

...tells us where the selection of text ENDS.

Since text can be selecting dragging left-to-right or right-to-left this does not INFER that the `anchorNode` is to the left of the `focusNode`.

What DOM/JavaScript method can be used to determine which referenced node is on the LEFT side of the text selection?

Clarification: this is to fix the bug for the `startContainer()` method (`window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer`) and thus that is an invalid suggestion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486509/range-object-differences-between-webkit-and-mozilla-based-browsers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would usually use [Node.compareDocumentPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.compareDocumentPosition) on `anchorNode` and `focusNode`, "left" is the moral equivalent of `DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING` (unless you have an RTL text of course). I assume that you actually want to know which comes first in the document and not the position on screen. Something like this will work:

```
let selection = window.getSelection();
let position = selection.anchorNode.compareDocumentPosition(selection.focusNode);
if (position & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING)
  alert("Left-to-right selection");
else if (position & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING)
  alert("Right-to-left selection");
else
  alert("Only one node selected");
```

Comment: For a full implementation you'd need to consider the case when `anchorNode` and `focusNode` are the same. For that, you need to compare `anchorOffset` and `focusOffset`.

Comment: @TimDown: Not really necessary, `compareDocumentPosition` returns 0 in this case. I've extended my example to spell out this case explicitly.

Comment: Oh, I suppose you're right from the wording of the question. I assumed the OP must be wanting to find out whether the selection was backwards or not.

Answer (score 3):

A method I've used for this uses the fact that setting the end of a DOM Range to be at an earlier point in the document than the start of the range will collapse the range:

```
function isSelectionBackwards() {
    var backwards = false;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
            range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
            backwards = range.collapsed;
            range.detach();
        }
    }
    return backwards;
}
```