# Inserting element just before selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to implement such a function on a web page: When called, it checks whether there are some text selection(often displayed as inverted colored text) on the page, if yes, insert an element `<img src="my.png"/>` just before the first word of the selection.

Pure JavaScript or jQuery code are both welcome, jQuery preferable. Thank you.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Maybe this [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text) can help. Replace the alert by the [jQuery .append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function.

Comment: The problem is that a selection can weave in and out of multiple DOM elements and hierarchies. Think of a case where a selection starts in the middle of some div, selects the rest of that div, some text in the parent div, then down into a nested list, and then maybe a div that's in the flow but has been absolutely positioned to the top of the page. What does "before the selection" mean in this case?

Comment: Another thought, if the text is right-to-left (eg Hebrew) wouldn't "before" mean actually "insert after but on the same line"? Isn't Chinese written top-to-bottom? There are different implications for al of these.

Comment: Yes, I've been aware of this. So I just want to place my ``<img>`` just at the  **starting point** of the selection. This should be no ambiguation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can propose you this solution :

```
$('#butt').click(function(){
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  if (sel.toString().length>0) { 
     var key = sel.anchorNode.compareDocumentPosition(sel.focusNode) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING
        ? 'focus' : 'anchor';
     var $elem = $(sel[key+'Node']), txt = $elem.text(), offset = sel[key+'Offset'];
     var $f = $(document.createTextNode(txt.slice(0, offset)));
     $elem.replaceWith($f);
     $(document.createTextNode(txt.slice(offset))).insertAfter($f);
     $('<img src=http://dystroy.org/flore/icon.png>').insertAfter($f);
  }
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ivufab/4/)

Comment: In addition, it should be checked, which comes first - the anchor node or the focus node: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710733/dom-determine-if-the-anchornode-or-focusnode-is-on-the-left-side
A selection can be made from left to right and from right to left. That determines the anchor and focus nodes. Quite tricky ...

Comment: Not much you can do but situations with text removed from the flow will break with this: http://jsbin.com/ilisay/1/edit

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Right but it's like the entire selection process which is weird and hard if you remove the elements from the flow. I think we can assume it won't happen in a real use case.

Comment: So you work primarily with good layouts made by people who know their css and don't use tables, huh? :P

Comment: @GeorgeMauer No, but I suppose this is dedicated to a kind of document, not a random web page.

Comment: Another thought, if the text is right-to-left (eg Hebrew) wouldn't "before" mean actually "insert after but on the same line"?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer You're questioning details of the specification. It would be easier to handle if you commented the question, not this answer. But I fear OP totally forgot he asked a question...

Comment: That's fair, and I think your answer is likely good enough, just that people often forget about globalization and I wanted to point it out for posterity.

Comment: Thank you dystroy, your solution works quite well on Chrome v27. But I really hope it can work in IE8. After replacing ``window.getSelection`` with a cross-browser one(provided by http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html), I'm stuck in ``anchorNode`` not supported in IE8 problem. Could you help improve it?

Comment: @JimmChen As I have no IE8 (in fact I have no Windows), I can't do that. Maybe you could have more luck using the [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Frange) object but I personally think there isn't any good reason to support IE8 today : it's too much expensive for the few not caring users...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="test">
    <span class="spanthatcontainstext">test</span>
    </div>
$(function(){
    var checkfortext = $('.spanthatcontainstext').length;
    if(checkfortext){
    $(checkfortext).prepend('<img src="" />');
    } else {
    //do something if there is no text
    }
});
```