# How to get character offset from a div without using selection methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg, offset

I'm trying to get the offset of a character after clicking on it (using a click handler and referring to his parentElement).
I saw a similar topic ([Getting character offset inside nested html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507779/getting-character-offset-inside-nested-html-tags)) but if possible I would like to do the same thing without using the range / selection methods (or at least without a selection by user input)

Here's an example in the picture below

[image]

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Comment: Not possible without selection and range. Notice, that you can create a selection and range programmatically based on user click.

Comment: you mean by triggering a double click when a single click is fired (in order to create a selection and get the range)? Or maybe creating an 'invisible selection' with the start offset equal to the end offset?

Comment: A single click and "invisible selection" i.e. collapsed selection is what I meant. A click is needed anyway, or is this an editable element?

Comment: No, it's not an editable element. By the way I got the idea but it's not pretty clear to me how to create (in code) the selection object in the exact point I click...